# Angular 9: how do I access child component instance from templateRef

Tags: angular, angular9

In angular 8, I was able to access child component from templateRef as below:

```html
<ng-template #templateName>
 <child-component></child-component>
</ng-template>
```

```js
@ViewChild('templateName') template;
    
const childComponent = template._projectedViews[0].nodes[1].instance;
```

But after migration application to version 9, everything has change. Now, I do not have projected views in template.

Now I see below attributes as part of templateRef

```
templateRef
 -> elementRef
 -> _declarationContainer
 -> _declarationView
```

How do I now access child component instance in angular 9?

Answer (score 0):

To access your child component, try like this:

```
  @ViewChild(ChildComponent) template: ChildComponent;
```

where `ChildComponent` is the class name of your child component.

Now with `template` you will able to access the child component's properties.

Comment: thanks @tushar, but is there any way to access it from template, because I am passing this template ref to another components method and used in ngTemplateOutlet. There, I need to access that child component.